# Coloured borders in algorithm2e

Tags: latex

I am trying to change the colour of the box around an algorithm2e environment in laTeX. The following code gives me the algorithm style I want, but with a black box around it, I would like to have it in red for example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[boxruled,algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm2e}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
Test Algorithm\\
Test Algorithm\\
Test Algorithm\\
Test Algorithm
\caption{ Test Caption}
\label{LARS Algorithm}
\end{algorithm2e}

\end{document}
```

[image: Curent result]

[image: Result I would like]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Very nice and clear first question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few tiny hacks one can smuggle the desired colour into the definition of the boxrule and the caption:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[boxruled,algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\@algocf@post@boxruled{\end{lrbox}\color{red}\framebox[\hsize]{\box\algocf@algoframe}\par}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@caption@boxruled}{%
  \hbox{%
    \color{red}%
    \vrule%
    \vbox{%
      \addtolength{\hsize}{-0.8pt}%
      \hrule\vskip\interspacetitleboxruled%
      \hbox to\hsize{\unhbox\algocf@capbox\hfill}\vskip\interspacetitleboxruled%
      \addtolength{\hsize}{0.8pt}%
    }% 
    \vrule%
  }\nointerlineskip%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm2e}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
Test Algorithm\\
Test Algorithm\\
Test Algorithm\\
Test Algorithm
\caption{Test Caption}
\label{LARS-Algorithm}
\end{algorithm2e}

test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated to your problem: better avoid spaces in labels